# Where something = 1; Not working on joined tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Despite the fact that available = 0 in all rows, I'm still getting all rows returned (as though available were 1) in this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM grfx_s_search LEFT 
JOIN grfx_s_search_data ON grfx_s_search.id = grfx_s_search_data.id 
WHERE ( tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) OR ( title REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) 
AND grfx_s_search_data.available = 1 
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0, 32
```

I'm fairly confused on this! I'm sure its an easy answer - I just cannot see what is going wrong here.

The question, simply stated:

Why am I getting rows returned when available = 0 in all items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `()`here:

```
WHERE (( tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) OR ( title REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) ) AND grfx_s_search_data.available = 1
```

If you do not so first the end is evaluated and the or.

Comment: So subtle! I would not have found that easily. A simple extra set of parenthesis.

Comment: @1Up That is easy mathematics.

Comment: @1Up:- On a side note: Try to use alias name for your tables when you are using it in JOINS, that makes your query more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
AND grfx_s_search_data.available = 0
```

not

```
AND grfx_s_search_data.available = 1
```

Also put  your OR condition in one bracket

```
SELECT * FROM grfx_s_search LEFT 
JOIN grfx_s_search_data ON grfx_s_search.id = grfx_s_search_data.id 
WHERE (( tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) OR ( title REGEXP '[[:<:]]abstract[[:>:]]' ) )
AND grfx_s_search_data.available = 0 
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0, 32
```